# Align Eye rig to Head rig

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I found some similar questions but no answers to my problem. So I am creating a little player character for a game engine and I want to be able to move the eyes on their own, so I must use bones to control them (I think contrains wont work in the engine). I've set the parent of the eye bones to be the head bone, made sure that only the eye bones are influencing the eye mesh and used a weight paint of 1 for the eyes and the head, but the eyes still don't move properly with the head if I rotate it. I had such problems before but didn't bother fixing them properly and just made sure i wasn't rotating the head too much, but I really want to get a good rig done :/.

If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask me :)
Thanks in advance.

File: http://www.mediafire.com/file/oxkqoz521cpmm82/rpgbase.rar

[image: This is how it should look (no rotation applied to the head)]

[image: With rotation and displaced eyes]

[image: weightpaint of the eye (should be 1.0 for each vertex)]

[image: weightpaint of the head (should be 1.0 for each vertex even though the bottom of the head seems to be a bit out of place?)]

Comment: Could you please share your file?

Comment: Done, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply the *Mirror* modifier. Then remove the eyes and the head from all vertex group (in the *Properties* editor > *Object Data* > *Vertex Groups*, click on the down arrow menu on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list and choose *Remove From All Groups*). Now reassign each eye to the bone that is supposed to control it, and assign the head mesh to its bone. There was a bone somewhere affecting the head, it made it deform so the eyes seemed to pop out.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked :)